# attach div after radio option based on ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using jquery to make a ajax request to determine if it should open a div when a specific radio button is clicked. I want the div that opens to appear directly under the radio button that is selected. I have the following that seems to work great:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".option_select").click(function() {
        $(this).next().after($('#show_pop'));
        $.ajax({
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          url: "/jrequest",
          data: {
            Action: "Do", 
            Option: po,               
          },              
          success: function (response) {                    
            if (response['SomeResponse']) {
                $('#show_pop').slideDown("slow");
            } else {
                $('#show_pop').hide();
            }                       
          },    
          error: function (xmlhttp) {
                console.log(xmlhttp);                   
          }
        });                     
    } 
    }); 
});
</script>

<input type="radio" name="Option1" class="option_select" value="Option1" /> Option 1
<input type="radio" name="Option2" class="option_select" value="Option2" /> Option 2
<input type="radio" name="Option3" class="option_select" value="Option3" /> Option 3
```

What I don't understand is why I can't do the "after" as part of the "success" of the ajax? For example, if I move the line

```
$(this).next().after($('#show_pop'));
```

To here:

```
....
  success: function (response) {                    
    if (response['SomeResponse']) {
        $(this).next().after($('#show_pop')); // This line does not seem to work here
        $('#show_pop').slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $('#show_pop').hide();
    }                       
 },
....
```

Then my div simply opens above my form, not below each option. Can someone explain why?

TIA!

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying to learn jquery but now I understand how these 2 posts relate

Answer (score 4):

`this` in the success callback is not the jQuery object but the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with this call to `$.ajax`).

There are a variety of solutions:

### Reassign `this`

As with other languages, JS allows you to reassign the `this` variable, which has a special meaning on its own depending on the scope.  Other variable names may not have such a restriction and can be used in lower scopes freely.

```
$(".option_select").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    /* snip */
        success: function () {
            $this.next();
        }
```

### Use `Function.bind` or `$.proxy`

[`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) allows you to set the context of a function to be called later.  This is similar to `.call` and `.apply`, but it does not immediately call the function.  The context set by `.bind` [takes precedence over one set by `.call`/`.apply`](http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/BDXRy/), so this can be used with ajax callbacks (which I assume use `.call` later, but I haven't verified this).

jQuery has a method [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) that does the same thing but is compatible with browsers where `Function.bind` is not available.  It works a bit differently and is a jQuery method rather than a `Function` method, but it doesn't matter much in this case.

```
success: function () { /* your code */ }.bind(this)
success: $.proxy(function () { /* your code */ }, this)
```

Both methods return a function.

Personally I find this to be the most *correct* solution although they will all work essentially the same.

### Use `$.ajax` `context`

You can set this with `$.ajaxSettings` in general, but that probably wouldn't make sense in this case.  This setting sets the context for all callbacks for `$.ajax`.

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
```

### Use of `this` in the examples above.

Note that the `$.ajax({` declaration does not create its own scope.  Thus it is safe to do:

```
$(".option_select").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({success: function () {}.bind(this)});
});
```

Above, `this` is still the DOM element jQuery sets as the context of the `.click` callback.  The only other scope created is by `function () {}`, but you use `this` outside of that.

[More information is available on the `$.ajax` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: While this is a duplicate, I think your solution here is better than the one suggested over there since your provide alternatives. Would you mind expanding on them a bit?